# Django gettext and gettext_lazy both imported with same name

Tags: python, django, translation

In [Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L9), `gettext()` and `gettext_lazy()` are both imported as `_`:

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _
```

How does that import method work, and which kind of function benefits from it?

Comment: BTW, that source code you link to does not import both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `gettext_lazy` is imported as `_`, `gettext` is imported as `gettext`. You’d generally want to use the lazy variant, but this returns a proxy object and not a string, so if you have a context where you need a string immediately, you may also need access to the non-lazy version. The lazy version is probably used more often, so it’s aliased to a nice short name.